# SDI text editor similar to Notepad, but less buggy

Tags: windows, text-editor

SDI = [Single Document Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_document_interface).

I'm using Notepad++ and I'm pretty happy with it, but it doesn't let me choose to view certain files in a separate window (separate from my main NP++ window which contains a bunch of tabs). To do that, I use Windows' simple Notepad app **alongside** Notepad++. It works well enough for me, since the files I open in Notepad are simple enough to not require advanced editing functionality. However, Notepad has some bugs related to handling newlines, which irritate me. I'd like to replace the Notepad piece of my setup with some other app, one that uses a SDI interface, but less buggy than Notepad. If this other app has some advanced editing features, that would be good, but is not necessary - the app can be as simple as Notepad is.

BTW I do know about NP++'s multiple-window command line flag, but it has some problems that stop me from using it (notably, the session handling).

Comment: Please [edit] and specify what the requirements for another editor are: what features of Notepad++ do you absolutely need? Also explain what *bugs related to handling newlines* you want to avoid (are they really bugs or shouldn't you write 'behavior'?)

Comment: And did you already search the site for [text editor](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+text+editor) or [code editor](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+code+editor)? Did you look at the 'related' posts that this site offers you in the right column (even when you are actually writing your question)?

Comment: After 20+ years, I doubt that "Notepad has some bugs related to handling newlines" (and, if it does, you ought to report them). It is much more likely that you have files with a mixture of line endings, which is simple enough to tidy up. However, are you sure that you are looking for another text editor? Do you just compare visually and hope that you see all the differences? Are you aware of tools such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which will perform side by side file comparison and highlight the differences?

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one window when using Notepad++: just drag and drop a tab somewhere else.

Example:

[image]

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've added a screenshot with six windows.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But there's a problem. When I create a new file in a N++ window, I can't drag it out of that window until I've written something in the file and saved it. Any fix? Also, is there another way to detach a tab from a window? Cause to drag a tab out of a window the window needs to be unmaximized (the tab needs to be dragged *outside* the window), and I'm using my window maximized.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CudaText editor](http://uvviewsoft.com).

It has tabbed UI, each command run (at Explorer) opens new window. And it has average functionality; with Python plugins like ST3.

Screenshot:

[image: CudaText]

Comment: Thanks, CudaText seems nice. Trying it out. I posted a question about it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/990740/cudatext-after-saving-undo-is-no-longer-available).